# how can i use routerLink for api request in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I am creating an application in angular cli 11 over a music group and I have the following problem with the routes:

In the database I have a table called "members" that contains all their information.
In the navbar, there is a drop-down where the members are displayed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq1G0.png)

this is the part of the code of menu.component.html:

```
<li *ngFor="let member of members">
   <a class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger" routerLink="/band/{{member.name}}">
      {{ member.name }}
   </a>
</li>
```

from this component i call to the api to get the info.
menu.component.ts:

```
export class MenuStComponent implements OnInit {

   members: Member[] = [];

   constructor(private data: DataService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
       //this.data.getAllMembers().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
       this.data.getAllMembers().subscribe(data => this.members= data);    
    }

 }
```

Also I have a component called member, that displays the info, and also calls to the api. This is the structure. member.component.html:

```
<div class="row align-items-center no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">

   <div class="col-xl-auto col-lg-auto"><img class="img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0" 
   src="http://localhost/web/back/web/{{member.image}}" alt="" /></div>
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-7">

            <div class="featured-text text-center text-lg-left">
                <h4>{{member.name}}</h4> 
                       
                <p class="text-black-50 mb-0">{{member.instrument}}</p>

                <br>     
                   
                <p class="mb-0 text-black-50 justificado">
                      {{member.description}}
                </p>
            </div>                      
        </div>                
</div>
```

On member.component.ts I have the same that menu.component.ts

In app-routing I have the next:

```
{
path: 'band/:name',
component: MemberComponent
}
```

My idea is that when I click on a member in the navbar it redirects me to web.com/band/memberName, and depending on which member you have selected, show me their corresponding information. How can I do that?

UPDATE: I solved it with the next:
member.component.ts:

```
export class IntegranteComponent implements OnInit {

  members: Member[] = [];
  member: string='';

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute, 
  private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.data.getAllMembers().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    this.data.getAllMembers().subscribe(data => this.members= 
    data);

    this.member = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  }
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: I have an idea, if in members.component.html I do a ngfor, and I compare the name that is in the url with that of the iteration (member.name), so that if they match, I show the data related to that name. That would be a correct way to do it?

Comment: Under my point of view it would be better if you use the url parameters to fetch the member details from the api instead of hardcoding all the member information. Check out  the solution I've proposed, this way you can read the member the user has selected and after this you could fetch the details from the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can actually navigate to the member page you can just capture the member name from the url parameter and then fetch the member from the api.

This is how you can get the url parameter:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

member: string;

ngOnInit(){
 this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
   this.member = params.name
 });
}
```

This way you can get the member name from the url and then fetch the member details from your api.

Comment: Sorry, but what do i have to put on "params"

Comment: You can leave it just like that and when executed it will store the member’s name on the member variable

Comment: It shows an error: Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Router'.

Comment: Make sure you imported ActivatedRoute, there’s other look alike libraries

Comment: You have to import ActivatedRoute and Params from @angular/router

Comment: That's true, thanks. another question, sorry to be heavy but i'm new to this. The code that you have given me I have put it in member.component.ts, then in member.component.html what exactly am I supposed to do?

Comment: You should put this code on the component that’s loaded when you want to check the member’s details, this is defined in your routes file, and after getting the name from the url you can fetch the member details from your api or wherever you store it. Once you have the details stored into a variable, and then from the html you can display it to the users.

Comment: Ok now I have a problem, when I click on one member and then click on another, the data does not load, I have to reload the page. How can i fix it?

Comment: Inside the subscribe you should fetch the member's data and store it into a variable, so every time you update the variable value the view should be updated. As you're subscribed to the url's param every time the params changes the code inside the subscription gets executed. Keep in mind that the current member variable I defined previously just stores the member's name in the url.

Comment: I don't understand very well, but It gave me an idea and I solved. Thank you so much :). I can't vote you because I'm new in here and Stackoverflow doesnt leave me